# CRON job and bash script to check battery state and beep

Tags: bash, cron, alert, monitor, battery

I recently changed desktop environments and the new one doesn't have a battery monitor.
I had managed to create a simple manual one by doing the following:

```
alias bat='upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"'
```

I would like to take this to the next level and create a script that not only checks the battery level but also beeps according to it, lets say it will beep if the battery percent is less then 20%.
I would then like to run it as CRON job, which lets say will run every 5 minutes.

I also used the following to create a beep sound which I liked:

```
alias beep='paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/message-new-instant.ogg'
```

Assuming the CRON part is covered, how would you write this script in bash, assuming you use the same command as used in 'bat':

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

1) Create a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

bat='upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"'
beep='paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/message-new-instant.ogg'

# This gets the integer percentage of current battery capacity
p=$(eval $bat | grep 'percentage' | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')

# if bat < 25% -> BEEP once
if [ "$p" -le 25 ] ; then
    eval $beep
fi
```

2) Set the permissions:

```
chmod 700 /path/to/script.sh
```

3) To set a cron job run `crontab -e` and add the following line:

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

which means the script will be run every minute.

Comment: Though `*/1` works, it can be replaced with `*` if the job is supposed to run every minute.

Comment: This script throws error [: Illegal number: 21%. This can be fixed by removing the % symbol from $bat



p=$(eval $bat | grep 'percentage' | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F '.'   ' { gsub("%","") } {print $1}')